# c++ Neural Network path finding not moving

Tags: c++, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I'm making a neural network in c++ to traverse a maze knowing where the player is, which 2d direction it can move in (up,down,left,right) and where the goal is, i can at any time get the distance of the player to the goal as well

thus far this is my code

```
std::string NeuralNetwork::evolve(player p)
{
        openMoves = p.getMoves();
playerPos = p.getListPos();
goalPos = p.getGoalPos();

values.clear();

for (auto item : openMoves)
    values.push_back(item);
values.push_back(playerPos.x);
values.push_back(playerPos.y);

if (outputs.size() == 0)
    outputs.resize(4);
if (inputs.size() == 0)
    inputs.resize(values.size());

for (int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++)
{
    inputs[i].srcValue = values[i];
    if (inputs[i].weightList.size() == 0)
    {           
        for (int j = 0; j < outputs.size(); j++)
        {
            inputs[i].weightList.push_back(dist(100) / 100.0f);
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < outputs.size(); i++)
{
    outputs[i].out = 0;
    if (outputs[i].theta == NULL)
        outputs[i].theta = dist(-100, 100) / 100.0f;//rand funct to produce int between -100-100 then divide by 100 to get theta between -1 and 1
    for (auto a : inputs)
    {

        outputs[i].out += (a.srcValue * a.weightList[i]);
    }
    outputs[i].finalOut = outputs[i].out / (1.0f + fabs(outputs[i].out));
    //outputs[i].finalOut = 1 / (1 + std::pow(exp(1), -(outputs[i].out - outputs[i].theta)));
}

for (int i = 0; i < outputs.size(); i++)//backwards prop
{
    float e = 1 - outputs[i].finalOut;
    float delta = outputs[i].finalOut * (1 - outputs[i].finalOut)*e;
    for (int j = 0; j < inputs.size(); j++)
    {
        inputs[j].weightList[i] += alpha * inputs[j].srcValue * delta;
    }
    outputs[i].theta += alpha * (-1)*delta;
}
```

the neural network is a function that's called every frame, the player starts in the top left and the goal is in the bottom right, the function returns a direction for the player to move in.
however, using backwards propagation each output final is never 1 which is what I use to determine its direction using

```
for (int i = 0; i < outputs.size(); i++)
{
    if (outputs[0].finalOut == 1)//left
    {
        return "01";
    }
    else if (outputs[1].finalOut == 1)//up
    {
        return "10";
    }
    else if (outputs[2].finalOut == 1)//down
    {
        return "11";
    }
    else if (outputs[3].finalOut == 1)//right
    {
        return "00";
    }
}
return "";}
```

however the function always returns no movement at all and i'm not sure why, even after a few minutes of waiting, there are no hidden layers to the network i'm starting simple with the inputs directly linking to the output
i'm unsure if my error calculation is correct to then adjust the weights. i'm unsure what i should be using to allow the ai to determine how to move

Comment: You need to debug it and check why you don't get non-zero entries in your network. There is not enough to reproduce what is going on here.

Comment: What purpose is there for the `for` loop if you return in its first iteration anyway and it does not even depend on the loop variable?

Comment: Please read about [mcve]. Just as an example: "the function always returns" what function? There is no function in the code you show here.

Comment: @eukaryota not on all branches there is a `return`, though if it does not return on the first iteration it probably also wont on any other...

Comment: @user463035818 the whole code is inside a function, outside of the for loop at the bottom it will return "" if no outputs are found

Comment: @user463035818 Right, I worded that wrong. NanoedStrux: The loop still has no purpose. If it doesn't return in the first iteration, it will just repeat the same tests with same outcome in the other iterations.

Comment: @eukaryota i see, I've just implemented a check to ensure the values aren't zero before it starts to calculate the weights. my cost function is the distance of the player to the goal.